Bisect not cutting all the way through?
I'm trying to bisect an object along a flat plane running along the x-y axes in order to separate it into two parts. When attempting to rip along the bisection, some of the geometry is not bisected:

The steps I followed:

enter edit mode and select all vertices
select the bisect tool
draw a bisecting line/plane roughly along the z-height I want
press "v" to rip off the selection and try moving it
some of the vertices remain and were not bisected

What am I missing?

In addition to the other answer I would consider just moving/straightening one of the existing edge loops to where you need the bisect to be and ripping that instead. Instead of trying to cut across the whole thing for no reason. Bisect tool will work best when you're working with more manageable geo and you mesh looks pretty dense.

You seem to simply have some other geometry there not related to the cut:

Even if you cut all the geometry above it, the operation does not remove topology around the cut, it will remain. You should just select all the geometry you want to move including the loop.
This is what's happening:


How do I select all the geometry above or below the cut?

Using any of numerous selection tools in Blender. There is no one right way. If it's a loop, you can alt+click an edge, if it doesn't form a nice loop, you can select an edge and ctrl+click on some other to select shortest path between them, or you could just use select box, or any other way. See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/selecting.html#

I just want to partition the mesh into "above" and "below" parts along a plane like "z=42.5" or something close to it, my goal is to simply extend the length of a handle. Am I using the right tool? I'd like to avoid having to click hundreds of edges if it's possible to specify a plane along which to cut.

Don't click hundreds of edges then. Learn to use selection tools in Blender. They are there to avoid clicking hundreds of times. Click dragging to box select for example is one click and it doesn't have a limit of how many elements it selects - could be millions.

What do you mean that the geometry is "not related to the cut"? Isn't the cutting plane bisecting that geometry? Or is it only touching the outer edges of the mesh?

No, you are not bisecting all geometry, just some. You bisect some edges and faces, but they are still connected to some other edges and faces and those remain where they are when you move your new edges.

@user84207 I added a GIF showing what's happening. The edges marked red just stay where they are.
